# Oracle ddl trigger not working

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, ddl

I'm new in oracle. I try to create trigger which will log ddl operations and insert it in my table.

```
CREATE TABLE LOG_DDL (
LOG_TIME date,
CURRENT_USER varchar2(255),
type varchar2(30),
name varchar2(30),
sysevent varchar2(30));

create or replace trigger log_ddl_trigger after ddl on database 
begin
insert into LOG_DDL(LOG_TIME,CURRENT_USER,TYPE,NAME,SYSEVENT)
values(
  sysdate,
  sys_context('USERENV','CURRENT_USER'),
  ora_dict_obj_type,
  ora_dict_obj_name,
  ora_sysevent
);
end log_ddl_trigger;
```

Here my code. The problem is that it doesn't work. No data is inserted in  LOG_DDL table when I am trying to perform insert, update or other operations. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have defined an `after ddl on database` trigger, not a DML trigger on the table.